# Is there an activity monitor(mac) GUI tool in Ubuntu?

Tags: system-monitor

The activity monitor in Mac OS is very useful.
You can check CPU/Disk/Mem/Network status for all the process.
For example:
You can check the upload/download speed of any process, you can even check which files are opened by a  process.
I wonder if Ubuntu has the same GUI tools.

There are a lot command lines tools available, but not very convenient.

Comment: Can these tools standardize their output formats so that they can be easily integrated into one GUI tool?

Comment: System Monitor, which is a reasonably alike GUI tool, has been included with every Ubuntu Desktop install for many years.

Comment: No, don't think Ubuntu has that.

Comment: Ubuntu comes with system monitor as basic install.  There are others also that you need to install, like system load indicator that sits in top panel, but uses system monitor as base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current system monitor Ubuntu has available immediately is it's own *System Monitor* located in the "Applications" folder. It works very similar to the one on Mac, but it lacks just one thing. That's the "sort by Network usage" feature that you might be looking for. The rest seems rather similar to Mac.

Comment: For network uses, you can use NetHogs. `sudo apt-get install nethogs` then launch `nethogs` from the terminal with sudo privileges

Answer (score 2):

There is System Monitor for that in Ubuntu. It has status information of the type you're looking for, but not everything you listed.